# HTML and CSS responsive bug

Tags: html, css

I was adapting my personal web site to smartphone, when I saw the bug you can see on this image:

[image]
[image]

The page width is more than screen size. By using Chrome inspector, it turned out the white space is `<html>`, so I have tried to edit the `meta` tag, but with no result.

[image]

This is the `meta` tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale = 1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

What can I do to remove this white space? Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: Check your margins on your parent containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all your code it's difficult to diagnose.

I would check for overflowing elements in your body. More than likely it's not your HTML that's overflowing, but some element in your page.